# Partial derivative of nested functions

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

I'm experimenting with signed distance functions and constructive solid geometry, and I've came accross a problem I can't wrap my head around.

I have a function for my distance field, that takes a 3D point $x$ and yields a value:

$$f : x \mapsto f(x)$$

Now, my csg object is moving through space. So I represent it's transform by a 4x4 matrix $T$, and it's velocity by a 4x4 matrix $V$. Using a matrix for velocity may be overkilled, but it allows to compute the transform at any moment $t$ using $T + t V$.

Now, let $$g : x, t \mapsto f((T + tV) x)$$ be the value of our signed distance field at any moment $t$, with transform position $T$ and velocity $V$.

We will define the multiplication between a 4x4 matrix and a 3-length vector by expanding our vector to the fourth dimension by adding $1$, computing the matrix-vector product, and then normalizing the 4-length vector by it's 4th component and taking the first 3 values, just like this is done in computer graphics.

Now, my question is: if I know the gradient of $f$, how can I compute the gradient of $g$ ? I'v been trying to write it down without any success. I've seen there is a [chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule) that can be expanded to multi variable functions, but even with that I failed.

#### Edit :

As asked, I've expanded the formulas and looked up the general rule. I'll try to make it clear.

we will rewrite everything using 1D-variables, so using again our functions we have :
$$f: x, y, z \mapsto f(x, y, z)$$
$$
h : x, y, z, t \mapsto (T + tV) \begin{bmatrix}
           x \\
           y \\
           z \\
           1
         \end{bmatrix}
$$

(where we then normalize by the fourth component, and keep the first three so that this gives us a 3D vector)

$$g: x, y, z, t \mapsto f(h(x,y,z,t))$$

We can then expand the formula for $g$, writing $T_{i, j}$ the $i, j$th elements of T (similarly for V) :

$$g(x, y, z, t) = f \left(\frac{f_1}{f_4}, \frac{f_2}{f_4}, \frac{f_3}{f_4}\right)$$

where :

$$f_i = (T_{i,1} + t V_{i,1}) x + (T_{i,2} + tV_{i,2}) y + (T_{i,3} + t V_{i,3}) z + (T_{i,4} tV_{i,4})$$

Now, the general rule from the provided link states :

$$D_{\mathbf{a}}(f \circ g) = D_{g(\mathbf{a})}f \circ D_{\mathbf{a}}g$$

Now, I have no idea where to go. Because the chain rule explain how to compute derivatives for nested functions, where I feel like what I have is a mapping from $g$ to $f$, but modifying the input variables, I don't see how to apply it.

Comment: Write down explicitly dimensions for $f$ domain and range and try to use  the rule for Jacobian matrices from your link.  Write what you got and I'll try to help, if it will be needed.

Comment: @zkutch should I also expand the matrices ? I feel like it's too much, and I don't know if there is another way around adding 32 parameters.

Comment: If/when you would like have explicit, expanded result, then there is no another way. But you can write formula for general member with indexes, $i,j$ for example, and use ellipsis. Or use operator form with total derivatives as it is under "General rule" from your link.

Comment: @zkutch I've tried out what you showed me, and edited the question accordingly.